# python Tkinter Capturing keyboard events save as one single string

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter, keyboard

is it possible to store keyboard events into one string? with the code below it only stores one char and prints it. but for a card reader or bar code reader, it contains a collection of character/ string not one character at a time. The goal is the save all the char pressed into text variable.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
     text= event.char
     text+= event.char
     print ("pressed", text)

def callback(event):
     frame.focus_set()
print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are creating `text` variable , everytime the `key()` function gets called, and text it only stores the last character you typed.

You can define text as a module level variable , and use that module level `text` inside your `key` function -

```
text = ''
def key(event):
    global text
    text+= event.char
    print("pressed", text)
```

Comment: Anand , how can I print text outside the function

Comment: just use `text` variable outside the function, it would contain all the characters pressed till now.

Comment: Great.  But if I try to print the text variable outside the function it doesn't print anything.

Comment: That must be if you try to print it at module level or such, the module only gets executed once at the starting, the text variable will only have values once you start typing, which is after the print happens, you can try printing the value of `text` variable inside the click function, and it will print the value when you click

Comment: ok great, now if I just return text in the key method then text will hold the value of the  keyboard events. now to use this value, if I call the method key(event:{char}) it takes a parameter of event:{char}. what will be event:{char}, i.e. the parameter for the above method so that I can call it later. I need to use the value which will be stored in the text outside the key method